# Mongoose - ObjectID as key?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I would like to have an object("ingredients" in example) in my mongoose model, where the keys are ObjectIDs, and their values are numbers. Is it possible to do so? How should I define my mongoose schema? You can find an example below.

Example JSON:

```
  {
    "_id": ""5a2539b41c574006c46f1a07",
    "name": "xyz",
    "ingredients": {
        "5a23f5e6159f5c3438c75971": 50,
        "5a23f60b159f5c3438c75972": 50,
        "5a255b04c9d9c40ac8927dd5": 50
    }
  }
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by keys are objectID and their values are numberes? Do you want to create your own key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use mix schema

```
{
    "_id": ""5a2539b41c574006c46f1a07",
    "name": "xyz",
    "ingredients": mongoose.Schema.Types.mix
  }
```

reference [how to create dynamic document keys in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38652592/how-to-create-dynamic-document-keys-in-mongodb)

insertion of dynamic key is so simple

```
insertData_dynamic_colone: function(collection, colone1, colone2) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[colone1] = "14";
    obj[colone2] = "15";
    dbObject.collection(collection).insertOne(obj, function(err, result) {
        assert.equal(err, null);         
    });
}
```

i know you'll also need to update dymanic key in future
take a reference [Update Mongo array: remove dynamic key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277437/update-mongo-array-remove-dynamic-key)

```
collection.update(
    {"_id": ObjectId("5a2539b41c574006c46f1a07")},
    {"$unset": {"ingredients.5a23f5e6159f5c3438c75971": ""}}
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the future reference :)

Comment: happy coding :)